# Installing ASP.net 4.5 on Windows 2012 R2

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis

Normally when I asked to setup IIS (ASP.net) on Windows 2012, I do pretty much routinely doing this step below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/installing-iis-8-on-windows-server-2012

1. List item
2. Open Server Manager.
   Under Manage menu, select Add Roles and Features
3. Select "Role-based"
4. Select the appropriate server (local is selected by default)
5. Select Web Server (IIS)
6. .Net Framework  3.5/4.5 Feature
7. Customize your installation of IIS, or accept the default settings that
   have already been selected for you, and then click Next
8. Click Install

I've encounter this following problem today:

(Missing Binding section when adding website)

[image]

Expected Result:

[image]

Anyone have idea how to fix  it? I already reinstall couple of times without any success.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add your `Web Site` under `Default Web site` , that is the reason you are unable to find the Binding Section : For Reference please check the below

[image: Check for your reference]

Comment: nah its actually opposite... when I've installed the IIS the default website is missing including default application pool.

Comment: @FernanVecina what do you mean by Opposite ?

Comment: i mean the default website doesn't exist. anyways I think I already found solution just waiting for my PM to get a permission from client to apply the fixed.  Saw similar issue it seems to fixed it just need to uninstall then reinstall  IIS and Windows Process Activation @Server Manager

Comment: @FernanVecina even that is what i'm trying to say , it by default creates the Default Web Site, but due to inproper installation , you need to create it under the Default Web Site (Your own created Default Web SIte ) , that is another reason for not able to find the binding , anyways .. glad you find out the solution